# Not a statement error with objects

Tags: java, object, for-loop, compiler-errors

I am getting a "not a statement" error in my code and i have no idea why
here is the code

```
          for (int i = 0; i < Champ.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Champ[i].length; j++) {
            if (Champ[i][j].getLegume() != null) {
                Champ[i][j].getNbJoursMatLegume() - jour; //HERE IS THE ERROR ....
                System.out.print(Champ[i][j].getNbJoursMatLegume() + " ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");

    }
```

All my variables are initialized and work fine, but i dont know why i can't do that operation

Comment: What do you expect that line to do?

Comment: a) what is `jour` b) what does `getNbJoursMatLegume` return c) assuming both are ints, it is the same as doing 5 - 2; **not very useful**

Comment: Champ[i][j].getNbJoursMatLegume() returns an integer for every object in the array. Jour is the day, its an integer. I just want it to do the integer minus the day ...

Comment: What does "do the integer" mean? If you're trying to print the result minus `jour`, add that to your print statement: `System.out.print((Champ[i][j].getNbJoursMatLegume() - jour) + " ");`

Comment: Actually, i am trying to change the getNbJoursMatLegume() variable by substracting the integer jour to it. But the result must be stored in getNbJoursMatLegume()

Comment: You need a setter for that. You can't update the return value of a getter.

Answer (score 2):

Following what has previously been written

You are doing a calculation here but not storing it anywhere:

```
Champ[i][j].getNbJoursMatLegume() - jour;
```

so you can either store it in a local variable

```
int result = Champ[i][j].getNbJoursMatLegume() - jour;
```

and maybe print it

```
System.out.println ("This is the value: " + result);
```

or based upon your code you can maybe set the value

```
Champ[i][j].setNbJoursMatLegume(Champ[i][j].getNbJoursMatLegume() - jour);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a calculation here but not storing it anywhere:

```
Champ[i][j].getNbJoursMatLegume() - jour;
```

Just store it like:

```
int result = Champ[i][j].getNbJoursMatLegume() - jour;
```

Comment: Would there be any way to change the getNbJoursMatLegume() variable by substracting the integer jour to it. But with the result being  stored in getNbJoursMatLegume()

Comment: Yes, but you need to use the setter if it exists. ` Champ[i][j].setNbJoursMatLegume(Champ[i][j].getNbJoursMatLegume() - jour);`

Answer (score 1):

> I am getting a "not a statement" error in my code and i have no idea
>   why here is the code

this code returns a value and you're not assigning it to a variable hence it's not a statement rather an expression.

```
Champ[i][j].getNbJoursMatLegume() - jour; //HERE IS THE ERROR ....
```

rather take the returned value and assign it to a variable:

```
int myResult =  Champ[i][j].getNbJoursMatLegume() - jour;
```

**EDIT**

> Would there be any way to change the getNbJoursMatLegume() variable by
>   substracting the integer jour to it. But with the result being stored
>   in getNbJoursMatLegume()

```
Champ[i][j].setNbJoursMatLegume(Champ[i][j].getNbJoursMatLegume() - jour);
```

Comment: Would there be any way to change the getNbJoursMatLegume() variable by substracting the integer jour to it. But with the result being stored in getNbJoursMatLegume()

Comment: @Adriann see Scary Wombats answer as he has answered it first but you can also see my solution above.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that because, as the message told you, `Champ[i][j].getNbJoursMatLegume() - jour;` is not a statement, it's an expression. The JLS mandates in Chapter 14, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html, "The sequence of execution of a program is controlled by statements, which are executed for their effect and do not have values." To be a statement, the line must do something with the value of the expression, such as assigning it to a variable or passing it to a method.

Also, *please* follow the Java naming conventions.